# Facebook - Custom Like action

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-wall

I have a site with stories with each story havinga like button.

Is it possible for when someone presses the like button, the story title is published on the users FB wall along with our company logo (in an iFrame)?

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that can help me.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The like will go on the users wall if they fill in the dialog box that Facebook shows after the user clicks the like button.  To ensure this can happen, be sure that the URL being liked has the correct og: tags specified.  Try parsing the URL in Facebook's linter tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

Comment: - however, I may have not explained it clearly enough.  I have a blog.  I need to be able to 'like' every different post and have each specific post appear on the users wall.  I have:       `code`  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp&ref="ttt">
</iframe> `code`  - Am I way off in what I am trying to do?                                 Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: Correct, if you program the OG tags on each blog entry to point to the correct url, then the correct link will appear on the user's wall when they submit the form.  Please run your URLs thru the linter to ensure you have your OG tags correct.